# border-shadow with linear-gradient combinate with background-image with linear-gradient?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to make a div with a gradiant: white to transparent. I add a red bow shadow on it, but I need the box-shadow effect respect the same gradient to transparancy than the box her-self!

Like we see http://jsfiddle.net/by57bkgy/ it's not good here, I don't want red effect at the left of my div.

I tried `box-shadow(0px 0px 2px 1px linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0, red 10%, red 100%));` but don't work.

How can I do a linear gradiant red to transparent on box-shodow?

thx.

EDIT I tried with `-webkit-mask:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0, white 10%, white 100%);` but box-shadow is ignored....

Answer (score 0):

Just change the div gradiant from (white, **transparent**) to (white, **the background -color of the  element in which the div is placed**).

There is no css support for gradient shadow

Comment: Impossible. The background of my div container is him self a linear-gradient too, not a fixed color.